# I'm getting an Exception in Java Swing, but the program continues to run fine. Should I be worried?

Tags: java, swing, exception, swingworker

I'm using a SwingWorker to update parts of the GUI, and I'm relatively new to using them so I'm not sure what's causing this or if it's important.  Basically, when this one big process finishes collecting data from online, the SwingWorker tells a JTable to update with the new information.  And it does, and the GUI works exactly as it should.  However, the console prints this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19 >= 18
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5718)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2114)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:725)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1482)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1413)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

And I hate this Exception, because it doesn't point to anywhere in *my* code.  I know what happens right before this Exception, as I'd been trying to figure this out on my own for a while, but there's no point I can find where an ArrayOutOfBoundsError should be possible. I'm fairly certain it has something to do with updating the JTable, but the table works fine.

So, what I'm asking is, can anyone give me an idea as to why this is happening, and, should I even be concerned, since the program still works fine?

Edit: After extensive testing, I've determined I'm incapable of reproducing this Exception in another program.  I've also found that it happens at a random time, but always after a call to a certain method in another class.  This call is made from the process() method of the SwingWorker, and all it does is remove all rows from the DefaultTableModel, then add rows containing the new information, one at a time in a for loop.  By printing to console, I've found that the Exception will be thrown before the for loops starts, after it ends, or at some random time during the for loop.  I've had the entire thing run without the Exception occurring. This a general version of the method in question:

```
    for(int i = table.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        model.removeRow(i);

    for(InfoObject o : listOfInfoObjects) {
        int[] stats = o.getStats();
        model.addRow(new Object[] {o.getName(),
        stats[0], stats[1], stats[2], stats[3], stats[4], stats[5]});
    }
```

I don't know if that's any help but it's all I've got to add, sorry.

Comment: Post a [Minimal Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help sooner

Comment: Message is Clear , You are trying to access the 19th index of an array , While the array size is 18. You Should to Know that Arrays are 0 indexed

Comment: @AdnanAhmadKhan but it is occurring in java.util.Vector, not OP's code.

Comment: @AdnanAhmadKhan: there is no direct reference to any line of code that OP wrote, which makes it a little bit harder to fix.

Comment: Oh.. Yeah.. i have not noticed that .

Comment: Seems that this man had the problem like yours . Give a look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433879/awt-eventqueue-0-exception-when-openning-jframe)

Comment: Are you updating the UI from the `process` or `done` methods?  If not then you're violating the EDT contract...and yes, you should be worried.

Comment: You probably removed an element from a table model and forgot to fire an event to notify the view of that removal. When the view thus tries to repaint the table, it tries to access the now missing element of the model. Or you're modifying the table from outside of the EDT, as MadProgrammer rightfully suggests.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am indeed updating from the process() method of the SwingWorker.

Comment: Then you will need to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order for use to help you further

Comment: @JB Nizet How would you recommend I go about remedying that problem?  Sorry, you may be able to tell I'm relatively new to this, I've never manually fired an event, just seen the methods when looking down the list of available methods in Eclipse.  I'm not sure which of these methods to use, if any at all, or whether to fire it from the JTable or DefaultTableModel the table uses.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I will asap, sorry for the delay and omission in the first place

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is bad use of threading within your program. Swing runs a single thread called the Event Dispatch Thread and all changes to the controls, layouts, etc must be done from on that thread.

You can use `SwingUtilties.invokeLater` to execute code on the EDT.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html